# ¿Como configurar alertas con jquery y Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

tengo un dilema, me gusta como aparecen las alertas en mi sitio web, de hecho las configure con toastr de bootstrap con su respectiva libreria adicional
Las configure para que aparezcan siempre y cuando detecten datos en la consulta de validación al mover el mouse por que aun no he aprendido hacer alertas que se refresquen en automatico sin hacer nada.
Pero aqui entra el problema, cada vez que muevo el mause y le doy en el boton de la alerta Ok vuelve a aparecer en cuanto le doy ok
Quiero que solo aparezca una vez cada vez que refresco la pagina para que no aparezca en repetidas ocaciones.

el codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
 introducir el código aquí

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('mousemove',function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/resultados_prueba.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    notif: 1
                }
            }).done(function (respuesta) {
                if (respuesta != 0) {

                        $('#notificaciones').html(respuesta);
                        
                        toastr.info("Tienes integraciones pentienes ("+respuesta+") <br /><br /><button type='button' id='notif' class='btn btn-dark clear'>Ok</button>",'Notificación:',{
                            "preventDuplicates": true,
                            "progressBar": true,
                            "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
                         } );
                         
                    }
               
            }).fail(function () {
                //alert('algo salio mal');
            });
        })
        })
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Has probado a cambiar `.on` por `.one`? Esto permite que las funciones se ejecuten una sola vez: http://www.w3bai.com/es/jquery/event_one.html.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).one('mousemove',function(){ /*one ejecuta la función una sola vez*/
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/resultados_prueba.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    notif: 1
                }
            }).done(function (respuesta) {
                if (respuesta != 0) {

                        $('#notificaciones').html(respuesta);
                        
                        toastr.info("Tienes integraciones pentienes ("+respuesta+") <br /><br /><button type='button' id='notif' class='btn btn-dark clear'>Ok</button>",'Notificación:',{
                            "preventDuplicates": true,
                            "progressBar": true,
                            "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
                         } );
                         
                    }
               
            }).fail(function () {
                //alert('algo salio mal');
            });
        })
        })
        </script>
```

Comment: me soluciono el problema muchas gracias! jaja no conocia esa funcion